# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory (node-14/mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Deployed to a new server and now I'm getting this error. It worked for awhile, but something we added or maybe too much data in mongoose? I don't know what is causing this.

```
puump-deamon | <--- Last few GCs --->
puump-deamon | [28:0x55ca2d5b62c0]    76562 ms: Mark-sweep 4094.7 (4101.1) -> 4094.0 (4100.9) MB, 1650.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.095, current mu = 0.009) allocation failure scavenge migh
t not succeed
puump-deamon | <--- JS stacktrace --->
puump-deamon | FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I've tried this:

`"start": "npx pm2-runtime index.js --name='puump-daemon' --watch --node-args='-r esm --max-old-space-size=4096'",`

no affect

I also tried this `$ sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=655300` on host OS (we're using docker with node:14-alpine. Still fails